# Objective-C - Core Location - iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7.1

I have a code in a `UIViewController` that starts the location update:
`[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];`

Is working perfectly. But I need every time you exit this screen it stops updating the location and start again when I return.

**The first time it for updates. In other times it does not stop.**

Code for exit from view:

```
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
locationManager.delegate = nil;
```

Ihave tried also: (without success too)

```
[locationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
[locationManager stopUpdatingHeading];
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

locationManager.delegate = nil;
locationManager = nil;
```

It always update. But from the second time not stop update.

`didUpdateLocation` code:

`-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{
     [self addingMarkerUser];
}`

Comment: Where is that code being called *from*?

Comment: From `viewDidDisappear`

Comment: show ur didupdatelocation code

Comment: Have you try them in viewwilldisappear?

Comment: didupdatelocation code submited

Comment: Yes, i tried on viewWillDisappear also. Without success

Comment: @Gian Just to get the obvious out of the way, you have put a breakpoint down and made sure that the code is actually getting executed?

Comment: @JustSid Yes. Every time the code is executed

Answer (score -1):

You should put your code in the `viewDidAppear` and i suppose in your `[self addingMarkerUser]` you use something like this without the stop (if not, please provide the code) :

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init] ;
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:_currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

 if (!(error)) {
              //do something with the data.
              //then stop the update.
            [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

        }
    }];
```

If you do like that, every time your view appear, the location will start the update then stop once the data retrieve.

Comment: He is asking the opposite

Comment: I do not use geocoding. Just place the marker of the current location of the device on the map.